# Load a certificate using a pfx file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application in a hosting server and I'm trying to use the following code to load a pfx file and use it to sign a document in that server.

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(physicalPath of pfx file, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

but in the hosting server gives me the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.  The specified network password is not correct.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The specified network password is not correct.

I used that code because the the hosting server provider doesn't allow me to install a certificate so I supposed using pfx file with the private key inside I can solve the problem but it's not....
The provider answered me that probably that code (or my account) is trying to access some protected areas in the operating system... is it true ? is there a workaround ?

Comment: It says the password is incorrect...

Comment: yes, but the password to open the pfx file is surely correct because in my PC the code runs without any problem... I tried also to add this code to be sure the password is correct:                                                              System.Security.SecureString a = new System.Security.SecureString();
            foreach (char c in password)
                a.AppendChar(c);
            a.MakeReadOnly();

Answer (score 2):

What you are actually trying to do is that you are importing the PFX file through the code , the Enum MachineKeySet , essentially notifies the X509 contructor to have Private keys  stored in the local computer store rather than the current user store.

Of course in that case your process will need necessary access to the certificate store of the computer and will try to write data which is not allowed by default.

You can instead try this method

```
[System.CLSCompliant(false)]
public X509Certificate2 (string fileName, System.Security.SecureString password);
```

Comment: Where should I write those instructions sir ? If I place them inside my class I have an error like "my class doesn't need an attribute like clscompliant because the assembly has no clscompliant attributes. If you mean instead to write my instruction without the MachineKeySet enum parameter, I've already tried that but the error I received is always the same "wrong network password"

Comment: actually you just use the function , you should leave the attribute out ( not required to be put ).. Hope this helps..

Comment: actually I already tried to use the function in this way: X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(physicalPath of pfx file, password); but the error message is the same...