ASP.NET - The specified network password is not correct - X509Certificate2
I have .NET web application where trying to import the certificate using the "X509Certificate2".
While importing, getting the "The specified network password is not correct.". The certificate is password protected .pfx file and I'm providing the password too while importing the certificate. Here are the steps to produce the issue:
In Global.asax.cs file, loading/importing the certificate on Application_Start by using:
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("path_to_pfx_certificate_file"),
"password",X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

It's breaking and throwing the exception "The specified network password is not correct".

I tried multiple solutions like:

Setting user profile true in IIS
Setting up multiple key flags like (DefaultKeySet, MachineKeySet, UserKeySet etc)

But nothing works.
Any help would be appreaciated.

Your ASP.NET runtime process runs under the SYTEM OR NETWORK SERVICE account ( do not recollect which one ) and the process does not have the necessary access to the private key of the certificate in particular .

Also this is a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54184951/load-a-certificate-using-a-pfx-file

Does this answer your question? Load a certificate using a pfx file
